# Use eigenvalues to find formula for recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, diagonalization

**(1) Sequence $ \{a_n\} $ is defined as $ a_{0} = a_1 = a_2 = 1  $
and**

$ a_n = 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3}, for. \  n \geq 3$.

Find a general formula for $ a_n $

I have only solved recurrence relations for n >= 2 so far in my class, I am not sure as to how I should extend it to n >= 3?

**Edit: P =**
[image]

(2) $ C = \begin{pmatrix} 2 &2 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 3  \end{pmatrix}\ $. **Diagonalise the matrix in 3 ways so that the diagonal matrices $ D_1, D_2, D_3 $ are different.**
I found it's eigenvalues to be

$ \lambda_1 = 0, $ corresponding vector is $ (-1,1,0) $.

$ \lambda_2 = 1, $ corresponding vector is $ (-2,1,1) $

$ \lambda_3 = 3, $ corresponding vector is $ (0,0,1) $

Is it correct to say that $ D_1 =  \begin{pmatrix} 3 &0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}\ $. $ D_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}\ $ $ D_1 =  \begin{pmatrix} 3 &0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}\ $?

Comment: Ask separate questions

Answer (score 1):

*Hint for (1):* We have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ a_{n-1} \\ a_{n-2} \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 &7 & 6 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ a_{n-2} \\ a_{n-3} \end{pmatrix}
$$
whose characteristic polynomial is $x^3 - 7 x - 6$ (no surprises here).

Finally, $x^3 - 7 x - 6=(x + 1) (x + 2) (x - 3)$.

Comment: Thanks, I found the matrix P(edit in the qn) that diagonalizes A, but do I have to find the inverse of P directly in order to find $ a_n $?

Comment: @foc, not really. Once you know the eigenvalues, you know that $a_n = c_1 \lambda_1^n + c_2 \lambda_2^n + c_3 \lambda_3^n$ and you can find $c_1,c_2,c_3$ from the initial conditions.

Comment: @foc, check your work on $P$ at [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B0%2C7%2C6%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C0%5D%5D)